# how to increase response time in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, response

when filling a form in the software then if it takes more than 5 or 6 minutes it gives me an error like XML HTTP request response. Is there any way to increase the response time. The users of my software are very slow in writing.

please help me......

Comment: Are you sure it's because of time out? Usually a user's session lasts for 1 hour after the last activity or until the session cookie is deleted.

Comment: is there any other reason for the problem. the problem arises i submit the value after 5 or 6 minutes. ohterwise it works good.

Comment: Can you (a) share the actual response content and error code and (b) check the error logs for any exceptions?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal server error)

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal server error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this at the top of your PHP script(php.ini file) and let your script loose!

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

> After this, restart your local server

Place beloved code in  `.htaccess` to increase it,

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where is that sript in laravel? @kkpatel bro

Comment: you have to place that code in php.ini file @Ziaur Rahman Shishir

Comment: in local server i can do that but in online server how can I edit the code, is there any opportunity to increase the time in laravel framework. thank you very much brother @kkpatel for your response